# Construct a parameter set using the function "makeParamSet" with parameters already defined in the function

Tags: r

I am performing Latin Hypercube sampling from functions `"makeParamSet"` and `"generateDesign"` (package `"ParamHelpers"`) in R. Using the function `“makeParamSet”`, how can I include a variable that is already specified in the argument `“parameters”` of the function? Here is an example where `"b"` must be included between 0 and `"a"`:

```
set.seed(1)
ps <- makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("a", lower=200, upper=500), makeNumericParam("b", lower=0, upper="a"))
Y <- generateDesign(100, ps)
test <- data.frame(a = round(runif(5, min=200, max=500)), b = NA)

> test
    a  b
1 280 NA
2 312 NA
3 372 NA
4 472 NA
5 261 NA
```

**Problem**:

The code `ps <- makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("a", lower=200, upper=500), makeNumericParam("b", lower=0, upper="a"))` doesn't work.

**Expected result**:

In the 1st row of the data frame `"test"`, `"b"` must be between 0 and 280.

In the 2nd row of the data frame `"test"`, `"b"` must be between 0 and 312.

In the 3rd row of the data frame `"test"`, `"b"` must be between 0 and 372.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the bound on `b` as a "forbidden region".  For example,

```
set.seed(1)
ps <- makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("a", lower=200, upper=500),
                   makeNumericParam("b", lower=0, upper=500), 
                   forbidden = quote(b > a))
Y <- generateDesign(100, ps)
```

According to the documentation in `?makeNumericParam`, you should also be able to 
do this with `require = quote(b < a)` in the `makeNumericParam` call, but I found this put `NA` values into the result unless I *also* had the `forbidden` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much user2554330 for your answer. Great ! It works. Is it possible to put several conditions in the `forbidden` argument? For example, `forbidden = quote(b > a, d > c, f > e)` Thank you for your help.

Comment: I expect  `quote(b > a | d > c | f > e)` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much user2554330 for your answer.  This works for the example of my post. But I found an example where there is a problem : `generateDesign could only produce 98 points instead of 100!`

Comment: Here is the example: `ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45), 
                   forbidden = quote(b > a | d > c | f > e))
Y <- generateDesign(100, ps)`

Comment: Increase the `augment` argument to `generateDesign`.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much for your answer.